# Fast tag replacements

Tags: python, stackexchange, automation

This uses the Stack Exchange API to quickly batch replace tags in questions.

I still need to fully comment and make the Wiki, but are there any glaring mistakes in it?

I have tried to use `try: except:` wherever I can to prevent any errors, and have attempted to make it compatible for Python 2 and Python 3.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Version 1.0.3

global HTML
global fetch
import requests
import webbrowser
import json
import sys
import os
import time
from time import sleep as update
import math as maths    
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    input = input
try:
    import HTMLParser
    HTMLParser=HTMLParser
except NameError:
    import html.parser
    HTMLParser=html.parser
HTML=max
fetch=True*8**2-4

def kill_code(reason='No Message'):
    sys.exit(reason)
    exit(reason)
    quit(reason)

# uses os.popen to get the terminal size.
def get_width():
    global width
    try:
        width = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()[1]
        supported=True
    except IndexError as error:
        width = 50
        supported=False
    width = int(width)
    return supported

# Prints out a spacer like ---------- the width of the console. If width is not supported, it will be 50 wide.
def spacer():
    get_width()
    print ('-'*width)

# Creates a loading bar like [========     ] the width of the console. Updates with get_width() each time it's called.
def loading_bar(n,i):
    if get_width():
        factor=(n/(width-2.0))
        n=int(maths.floor((n)/factor))
        i=int(maths.floor((i-1)/factor))
        sys.stdout.write('['+'='*(n-i)+' '*(i)+']')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        print ('=')

def check_for_error(response_JSON):
    try:
        kill_code('Got error message: '+response_JSON['error_message'])
    except KeyError:
        return False

# Checks that the API hasn't said to go away. If it has it sleeps for the time allocated.
def backoff(response_JSON):
    try:
        backoff = int(response_JSON['items'][0]['backoff'])
        print ('Told to backoff, waiting for '+str(backoff)+' seconds.')
        for i in range (backoff, 0,-1):
            loading_bar(backoff,i)
            time.sleep(1)
        spacer()
    except KeyError:
        pass

def site_format(site):
    special_sites=['askubuntu','stackoverflow','superuser','serverfault','stackapps']
    if site not in special_sites:
        site=site+'.stackexchange'
    return site


# Perform the search for 
def get_from_search(site,batch,tag,key,token):
    response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search",
          data={'tagged': tag,
                'site': site,
                'key': key,
                'pagesize': batch,
                }
            )
    response_JSON = response.json()
    quota_remaining = response_JSON['quota_remaining']
    print (str(quota_remaining)+' requests left. Used '+str(10000-quota_remaining)+' today.')
    backoff(response_JSON)
    check_for_error(response_JSON)
    return response_JSON[u'items']

#
def get_ids_from_items(items):
    ids = []
    for question in items:
        ids += [question[u'question_id']]
    return ids

#
def get_tags_from_ids(question_IDs,key,token,batch):
    all_data=[]
    n=len(question_IDs)
    i=n
    for q_id in question_IDs[:batch]:
        response = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+str(q_id),
              data={'site': site,
                    'access_token': token,
                    'key': key,
                    'filter': '!9YdnSIoKx',
                    }
                )
        response_JSON = response.json()
        backoff(response_JSON)
        check_for_error(response_JSON)
        quota_remaining = response_JSON['quota_remaining']
        all_data+=[response_JSON]
        loading_bar(n,i)
        i-=1
    print (' '*(width+2))
    return all_data

#
def change_tag(q_tags,tag_id,tag,replacement_tags,site):
    try:
        tag_id=int(tag_id)-1
        new_tag=replacement_tags[tag_id]
        q_tags[q_tags.index(tag)]=new_tag
        print ('Tagging with ' + ' '.join(q_tags)+'\n')
        site=site_format(site)
        print ('If you make a mistake please continue and when you finish editing visit http://'+site+'.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=revisions')
        return q_tags
    except ValueError as error:
        tag_id=0
        print ('Skipping because '+str(error))
        return False

def print_tags(replacement_tags,enter_command):
    print_text='\nWhat should happen to this? Press enter to '+enter_command+', press '
    for i in range(len(replacement_tags)-1):
        print_text+=str(i+1)+' for '+replacement_tags[i]+', '
    print_text+='or '+str(i+2)+' for '+replacement_tags[-1]+'.'
    print (print_text)

def show_tags(all_data,tag,replacement_tags,site):
    formed_data=[]
    for q_response in all_data:
        q_tags = q_response['items'][0]['tags']
        spacer()
        to_print=', '.join(q_tags)+' : '+str(q_response['items'][0]['question_id'])+' : '+HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(q_response['items'][0]['title'])
        if len(to_print) > width:
            print (to_print[:width-3]+'...')
        else:
            print (to_print)
        spacer()
        print_tags(replacement_tags,'view question content')
        user_input = input()
        if not user_input:
            spacer()
            print (str(q_response['items'][0]['question_id'])+' : '+HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(q_response['items'][0]['title'])+'\n')
            print (HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(q_response['items'][0]['body_markdown']))
            spacer()
            print_tags(replacement_tags,'skip')
            user_input=input()
        new_tags = change_tag(q_tags,user_input,tag,replacement_tags,site)
        if new_tags:
            q_response['items'][0]['tags'] = new_tags
            formed_data+=[q_response]
    return formed_data

# Goes through the submitted edits and sends them to the site.
# Because edits appear on front page, there is a time limit.
# At a minimunm, it sends NO MORE than 1 per minute, and defaults to 1 minute 30 seconds.
# This is not user customisable via input. IT HAS TO BE CHANGED HERE.
# Think carefully before you change the value.
def send_edits(formed_data,key,token,site,tag):    
    wait = 10
    print ('\nFinished tagging, sending edit data. Please wait '+str(max(60,wait))+' seconds between each edit.')
    failed = []
    titles = []
    errors = []
    n=len(formed_data)
    i=n
    for question_data in formed_data:
        loading_bar(n,i)
        q_id = int(question_data['items'][0]['question_id'])
        try:
            body_markdown = str(HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(question_data['items'][0]['body_markdown']))
            title = str(HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(question_data['items'][0]['title']))
            send = True
        except (UnicodeEncodeError,UnicodeDecodeError) as error:
            send = False
        tags = question_data['items'][0]['tags']

        if send:
            response = requests.post('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+str(q_id)+'/edit',
                  data={'body': body_markdown,
                        'comment': 'removed '+tag+' tag',
                        'tags': ' '.join(tags),
                        'title': title,
                        'access_token': token,
                        'site': site,
                        'key': key
                        }
                    )
            response_JSON=response.json()
            backoff(response_JSON)
            check_for_error(response_JSON)
            if i > 0:
                update(HTML(fetch,wait))
        else:
            failed += [q_id]
            titles += [question_data['items'][0]['title']]
            errors += [error]
        i-=1
    return [failed,titles,errors]

# Retrieves auth token from authtoken.txt, or get's user input.
# The user is redirected to http://stackexchange.com then my site in the default webbrowser to get this token.
# The token is 24 chars long, and validated as that.
def get_auth():
    try:
        token=open('authtoken.txt','r').read()
    except IOError:
        print ('No authentication file found.')
        auth_true=input("Do you want to get your authentication token? You have to do this to use the program (Y/n) ").lower()

        if (auth_true != 'n'):
            savout = os.dup(1)
            os.close(1)
            os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
            try:
                webbrowser.open("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4921&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=http://timtjtim.github.io")
            finally:
                os.dup2(savout, 1)
            token=input('Please enter your SE authentication token here: ')
    if len(token) != 24:
        print ('Invalid token. Retying')
        open('authtoken.txt','w').write('')
        get_auth()
    else:
        print ('Got token')
        open('authtoken.txt','w').write(token)
        return token

def display_failed(failed,titles,errors,site):
    print ('')
    if failed:
        display_list = input('Sent edits. '+str(len(failed))+' edits failed. Do you want to see a list? (y/N) ').lower()
        site=site_format(site)
        if display_list == 'y':
            for q_id,title,error in zip(failed,titles,errors):
                spacer()
                print ('"'+str(title)+'" was not edited sucsessfully. Error:'+str(error))
                print ('You may wish to edit it yourself, the url is http://'+site+'.com/questions/'+str(q_id))
                spacer()
            open_all=input('Do you wish to open all these questions for manual retagging? (y/N) ').lower()
            if open_all == 'y':
                for q_id in failed:
                    savout = os.dup(1)
                    os.close(1)
                    os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
                    try:
                        webbrowser.open('http://'+site+'.com/questions/'+str(q_id))
                    finally:
                        os.dup2(savout, 1)
    kill_code('Finished Tagging')

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    site=input('Site: ').lower()
else:
    site = sys.argv[1]

# Get the tag to remove from questions
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    tag=input('Tag: ').lower()
else:
    tag = sys.argv[2]

# Get the number of questions to edit in batch. Max 30
if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    try:
        batch=min(30, int(input('Number to edit at once: ')))
    except ValueError:
        print ('Invalid input. Setting to 5')
        batch=5
else:
    try:
        batch=min(30, int(sys.argv[3]))
    except ValueError:
        print ('Invalid input. Setting to 5')
        batch=5

#print (batch)

# Get the number of 
if len(sys.argv) < 5:
    replacement_tags=input('Tag alternatives: ').lower().split()
else:
    replacement_tags = sys.argv[4:]

# Check the replacement tags are valid (i.e. there is 1 or more)
if not replacement_tags:
    print ('Invalid replacement tags. Exiting')
    kill_code()

token = get_auth()
key = 'hDZI3p7wr3JAf1t)ccIIHA(('
items = get_from_search(site,batch,tag,key,token)
question_IDs = get_ids_from_items(items)
print ("Got IDs, fetching data")
all_data = get_tags_from_ids(question_IDs,key,token,batch)
formed_data=show_tags(all_data,tag,replacement_tags,site)
results=send_edits(formed_data,key,token,site,tag)
failed=results[0]
titles=results[1]
errors=results[2]
display_failed(failed,titles,errors,site)
```

Comment: I'm tempted to DV on the moral grounds that this ***is not*** how retagging should be done, but ++ for the good question.

Comment: I'm just morally opposed to removing tags like this. IMO time should be taken to really clean up each post. Ask Ubuntu is none of my business though. You've run this past their meta, right?

Comment: @RubberDuck I spoke to a mod in chat, and he said it's fine, just keep it rate limited. I base it on the tags at first (like boot, uefi and live-cd suggest system and apt, software-center suggest software) but also use the question body if I can't tell.

Comment: Cool. Just checking.

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Introduction

There's quite a bit of code here, so I'm just going to review one of your functions (`get_width`). You'll see that there's plenty here for one answer. Maybe some other reviewers will look at some of the rest of your code.

```
# uses os.popen to get the terminal size.
def get_width():
    global width
    try:
        width = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()[1]
        supported=True
    except IndexError as error:
        width = 50
        supported=False
    width = int(width)
    return supported
```

#### 2. Review

1. The name of the function is ambiguous: get the width of what? Something like `terminal_width` would be better.
2. There's a comment but it would be better if this were a docstring: then you could read it using `help(get_width)` from the interactive interpreter.
3. The comment says:

   ```
   # uses os.popen to get the terminal size.
   ```

   but this is misleading. Someone who just read the comment might think that `get_width` *returned* the terminal width, but in fact the function stores the terminal width in a global variable and returns something else.
4. It's not clear what the "something else" is. The variable name is `supported`. But what is it that's supported or not?
5. It's a bad idea to use global variables to pass state around — it's all too easy to forget whether or not you've updated them. I presume that you're doing this because `get_width` has two pieces of information to return (the terminal width, and whether something or other is supported). But in Python, functions can return multiple values using a tuple, like this:

   ```
   return supported, width
   ```
6. The code says:

   ```
   except IndexError as error:
   ```

   but `error` is not used, so write:

   ```
   except IndexError:
   ```
7. There's no need to call `int(width)` in the `IndexError` case, as the code has already set `width = 50`.
8. If `stty` fails for some reason, for example:

   ```
   stty: stdin isn't a terminal
   ```

   then `int(width)` will raise `ValueError`. This needs to be handled.
9. `stty size` reports `0 0` if it can't determine the terminal size. This needs to be handled.
10. The *mode* argument to [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) defaults to `'r'`, so there's no need to specify it.
11. The code opens a pipe using [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) but does not close it. It happens to be the case that CPython automatically closes files when the reference count of the associated file object goes to zero, but this is not something you want to get into the habit of relying on because other Python implementations have different behaviour. Use the `with` statement to ensure that the pipe is closed:

    ```
    with os.popen('stty size') as f:
        try:
            width = int(f.read().split()[1])
            # etc.
    ```
12. [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) runs a subprocess using a shell. This wastes a process (you don't need any shell features, you only want to run `stty`) and is a bad habit to get into because the shell has to parse the command you give it, and in more complicated situations that can be a security risk. It would be better to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to run `stty` directly, bypassing the shell.
13. Instead of calling the external process `stty`, why not interrogate the terminal directly? The idea is to use the [`ioctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) (I/O device control) system call via the Python interface [`fnctl.ioctl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl), passing the `TIOCGWINSZ` ("terminal I/O control: get window size") command, which returns a pair of `unsigned short` (16-bit) values that can be decoded using [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

    ```
    rows, cols = unpack('hh', ioctl(sys.stdout, TIOCGWINSZ, '0000'))
    ```

    This is exactly what the `stty size` command does, except that you are avoiding the extra process.
14. If you can't determine the terminal size via the `ioctl` call, it's a good idea to fall back to consulting the environment. Some shells set the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environment variables.
15. To make the function more generally usable, why not return the rows as well as the columns? You have the value in your hand, so why not return it?
16. You use the `supported` flag to decide what kind of progress bar to draw. Presumably what you actually want to know is whether the standard output is connected to a terminal? But in that case you should just use the built-in [`os.isatty`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty).

#### 3. Revised code

```
from struct import unpack
from fcntl import ioctl
import os
import sys
from termios import TIOCGWINSZ

def terminal_size(fd=sys.stdout, default=(25, 80)):
    """Return the size of the terminal attached to fd, as a tuple (rows,
    columns). If the size can't be determined, return default.

    """
    def fallback(value, key, default):
        if value > 0:
            return value
        try:
            return int(os.environ.get(key, default))
        except ValueError:
            return default

    size = unpack('hh', ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, '0000'))
    return tuple(map(fallback, size, ('LINES', 'COLUMNS'), default))
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I won't use all the advice but a lot of this is very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

This is not about the functionality of the code, just it's presentation and readability.

You sometimes don't have spaces around the assignment (e.g. `HTMLParser=HTMLParser` instead of `HTMLParser = HTMLParser`).

That example shows some redundancy as well; `HTMLParser` is already itself, so there is no need to assign it.

And the way you have imported HTMLParser is not very well commented. I would go for something more like:

```
try:
    import HTMLParser  # Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import html.parser as HTMLParser  # Python 3.x
```

Note this is an ImportError, not a NameError. You should test this with Python 3.

Most of your comments should really be docstrings, as in:

```
def spacer():
    """
    Prints out a spacer like ---------- the width of the console.
    If width is not supported, it will be 50 wide.
    """
    get_width()
    print('-' * width)
```

(Note that I added a linebreak to make it not exceed the line limit.)

---

Now I'm going to review one of your functions, `loadin:

```
# Creates a loading bar like [========     ] the width of the console. Updates with get_width() each time it's called.
def loading_bar(n,i):
    if get_width():
        factor=(n/(width-2.0))
        n=int(maths.floor((n)/factor))
        i=int(maths.floor((i-1)/factor))
        sys.stdout.write('['+'='*(n-i)+' '*(i)+']')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        print ('=')
```

Now, I'm going to assume you are using [Gareth Rees's `terminal_size`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/92139/61114). The code needs to be adjusted to use it. I also accounted for the `/ 0` case and that `int(math.floor(x)) = int(x) (if x is a float / int)`

```
def loading_bar(n, i):
    """
    Prints a loading bar like "[===    ]" if the terminal has width and
    it is greater than two. Otherwise, it prints '='.
    """
    if os.isatty(sys.stdout):
        _, width = terminal_size()
        n = float(n)  # To use float division
        i = float(i)
        try:
            factor = n / (width - 2)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('=')
            return
        n = int(n / factor)
        i = int((i - 1) / factor)
        sys.stdout.write('[' + '=' * (n - i) + ' ' * i + ']')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        print('=')
```

Now your `sys.stdout.write` could really be merged into one write then flush.. Also, you could use `str.format` instead of concatenation.

```
        try:
            sys.stdout.write('[{0}{1}]\r'.format('=' * (n - i), ' ' * i))
        except AttributeError:  # Older Python 2 versions don't have string formatting
            sys.stdout.write('[%s%s]\r' % ('=' * (n - i), ' ' * i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Now, the variable names aren't very specific. What are `n` and `i`? I think, as a loading bar, it should take a percentage the bar is full. Also, to avoid the string formatting and many concatenations, I would premake the bar in a variable then add the `[]`. So, the final code using percentages would be:

```
def loading_bar(percentage_full):
    """
    Prints a loading bar like "[===   ]" that is percentage_full% full.
    If the terminal doesn't have a determinable width, prints "=" 
    """
    if os.isatty(sys.stdout):
        _, width = terminal_size()
        if width <= 2:
            print("=")
            return
        filled = math.round(width * percentage_full * 0.01)
        # * 0.01 to turn percentage to decimal
        whitespace = width - filled
        bar = "=" * filled + " " * whitespace
        sys.stdout.write("[" + bar + "]\r")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        print("=")
```

Comment: The reason for repeatedly calling `get_width` is that a terminal's width can change, for example, if the user resizes the window. (I guess this was not obvious from the code, so it probably deserves a comment.)

Comment: @GarethRees I see your answer heavily reviewed that function. I have removed it from mine because df my misunderstanding

Comment: @Reticality Thanks for this answer. I assigned HTMLParser to itself for python 2 and 3 support - fixed that now. I will read through the answer when I'm back online this evening (UTC).

Comment: What is bar_length? Also it can't be print because otherwise it doesn't overwrite the previous line...

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I renamed it to filled but forgot to change it. I have changed it

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there are a couple of WTFs with the code.  I'll leave out the
already commented-on stuff.

- What/why is there `global HTML` and `HTML=max` in there?  That doesn't
  *do* anything except give it a new name.  In which case the `global`
  is still not needed.  IMO just don't do that.  Same goes for all the
  renamed imports, i.e. `update` a.k.a. `sleep`, `maths` a.k.a. `math`.
  The point is that the reader with higher probability *knows* what
  `math`, `sleep` and `max` are.  It is way easier to just keep the
  names instead of having to look up trivial name changes.
- What is `True*8**2-4`?  I now know it's `60`.  How about
  writing `60` instead and not keep the reader guessing what a boolean
  times an integer is.
- `kill_code` is overkill.  Either of those functions will exit the
  process.  So just replace `kill_code` with `sys.exit`.
  [Stack Overflow agrees with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used).
- The return value for `check_for_error` is never used, you can just
  drop that in favour of `pass`.  Then again, it's cleaner to check for
  the existence of the key instead of catching the `KeyError` instead.
  In general it's also not good practice to kill the process if a
  minor condition fails, e.g. raising an exception (which in turn could
  be handled, or otherwise quit the process) is more future-proof.  I'd
  expect at least something like the following instead (modulo the
  exception thing):

  ```
  def check_for_error(response_JSON):
      if 'error_message' in response_JSON:
          sys.exit(response_JSON['error_message'])
  ```
- The `'authtoken.txt'` opened in `get_auth` is never closed.  Use
  `with` as well, otherwise you're leaking file descriptors and that's
  never good.
- `get_auth` is called recursively, but the recursive call has no
  `return`, so if this fails on the first try it will return `None`
  regardless.

Minor things:

- `input = input` doesn't do anything.
- String formatting is easier with interpolation or `.format`.
- THere's both unicode and regular string literals used.  If possible
  use just of both forms.
- `get_ids_from_items` can be simplified:

  ```
  def get_ids_from_items(items):
      return [item['question_id'] for item in items]
  ```

  That also avoids creating all those single element lists.  Since that
  appears a number of times then other option there is to use `.append`
  instead (for the same reason).
- In `change_tag` setting `tag_id` to zero doesn't do anything.
- `quota_remaining` in `get_tags_from_ids` is unused.
- The iteration in `print_tags` can be made a little bit nicer with
  `enumerate` instead.
- Move everything on the top level into a `if __name__ == '__main__':`
  block, or even a `main` function.  It also wouldn't hurt to use
  `argparse` for command-line arguments.
- The sequence `response.json()`, `backoff()`, `check_for_error` is used
  three times - I'd create a new function for it.

In general it would be good to have more code reuse and reduce clutter
with all the mixing of UI messages and actual work.  More functions for
formatting stuff would also reduce the number of lines dedicated to
string manipulation.

Also some comments in the important places would be nice, i.e. why
the sudden low-level file descriptor manipulation with `os.dup` and
friends is necessary.